# ERROR : ROS2 RUN package not found

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*colcon build --packages-select* -build my package with this instruction.

trying to run a publisher node

ros2 run [package_name] talker

ERROR: package not found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348083/error-:-ros2-run-package-not-found/) by [rd112](https://answers.ros.org/users/53056/rd112/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-04-01

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-04-01**:
This is very limited information.
How is composed your package? Is it a python or cmake package? Does it install an executable named talker ? if yes to what location ?

Please consider profiding more information and relevant bits of code like your CMakeLists or setup.py/cfg

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-04-01**:
Did you source the setup file generated by the colcon build command? e.g. `install/setup.bash`

**Comment by [sabin](https://answers.ros.org/users/69139/sabin/) on 2021-02-02**:
Getting the same error, followed the tutorial step by step, using Python package on Windows. When I run ros2 run my_package my_node I get `Package 'my_package' not found`

**Comment by [sabin](https://answers.ros.org/users/69139/sabin/) on 2021-02-02**:
The issue was that I called `install/local_setup.bat` (as indicated in the tutorial). Calling '.\install\setup.ps1' fixies the issue.

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2022-03-08**:
Everytime you build a package, always remember to do (from your ROS2 workspace): `source install/setup.bash` and `source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash`

**Comment by [misty](https://answers.ros.org/users/58853/misty/) on 2022-04-04**:
@fabbro, why do I need to source two setup.bash files? i.e.,
source install/setup.bash and source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case I was running colcon build form inside the src directory in my workspace.
Like this:

```
~/ros2_ws/src$ colcon build
```

Running `colcon build` in the workspace root solved the issue:

```
cd ~/ros2_ws
colcon build
source install/setup.bash
```

and finally

```
ros2 run [package_name] [executable_name]
```

---

Originally posted by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) with karma: 500 on 2022-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carter12s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5109/carter12s/) on 2022-11-30**:
This worked for me! Thank you for your answer.

**Comment by [Ricky23](https://answers.ros.org/users/126672/ricky23/) on 2022-12-10**:
I tried using this but it didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have your ros2 configuration sourced from your shell's rc file (example: `source /opt/ros/<your version>/setup.bash` in the `.bashrc` file when using `bash`), then you need to source the appropriate install script for  your application:

When you open a new shell/terminal, `source install/setup.bash` for `bash`, etc.

If you do not have the line mentioned above in your rc file (for example, you prefer to control this manually), then you need to source both files.

(I find answers easier to digest than comments.  All of this info is in the comments.)

---

Originally posted by [randy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31679/randy/) with karma: 11 on 2022-06-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Micha Sende](https://answers.ros.org/users/23012/micha-sende/) on 2023-03-03**:
Opening a new terminal did the trick for me!